# How to make a .xml sitemap in ASP

Tags: xml, web, asp-classic, sitemap

I have a local news site and I wanna faster indexing by Google, Yandex and others. The SEO masters says that , the easiest way of it is sending a sitemap to search engines. My used script is so old 'n it written in ASP. I have a .asp extension sitemap but Google is preffering .xml to others. So, how can I convert a .asp extension to .xml ? 
Thanks.

Comment: you need to create a url rewrite rule. have a look at [Creating Rewrite Rules for the URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) to learn how to create a rewrite rule by using IIS Manager, will be a good start for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sitemapindex and add your sitemap to that. like this:

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<sitemap>
<loc>https://www.yoursite.com/sitemap/ss.aspx</loc>
<lastmod>2020-05-03T17:07:27+00:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>https://www.yoursite.com/sitemap/videos.html</loc>
<lastmod>2020-05-03T17:07:27+00:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

introduce sitemap index to search engine